# Unable to pair WF & SP2013

Tags: workflow, workflow-manager

When I try to pair SharePoint 2013 with WF on Windows Server 2012 R2, it throws the following error:

Have tried with both HTTP and HTTPS

```
> Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite 'http://spfeapp01:37000'
> -WorkflowHostUri 'http://spfeapp01:12991' -AllowOAuthHttp -Force
> 
> Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite 'http://spfeapp01:37000'
> -WorkflowHostUri 'https://spfeapp01:12990' -Force
> 
> Get-SPWorkflowServiceApplicationProxy |
> Remove-SPServiceApplicationProxy -Confirm:$false
```

I could access the WF urls on IE as administrator, Have enabled Firewalls even though WF & SP2013 are in the same machine.

Updated on: Nov 7, 2014

```
11/07/2014 12:07:43.52  PowerShell.exe (0x244C) 0x2B08  SharePoint Foundation   PowerShell  6tf0    Medium  Entering ProcessRecord Method of Register-SPWorkflowService.    8441be6c-6699-40a2-8dde-60e52a69238f    
11/07/2014 12:07:43.52  PowerShell.exe (0x244C) 0x2B08  SharePoint Foundation   General adyrv   High    Cannot find site lookup info for request Uri http://localhost:37000/.   8441be6c-6699-40a2-8dde-60e52a69238f    
11/07/2014 12:07:43.52  PowerShell.exe (0x244C) 0x2B08  SharePoint Foundation   PowerShell  6tf0    Medium  Entering BeginProcessing Method of Register-SPWorkflowService.  8441be6c-6699-40a2-8dde-60e52a69238f    
11/07/2014 12:07:43.52  PowerShell.exe (0x244C) 0x2B08  SharePoint Foundation   PowerShell  6tf0    Medium  Leaving BeginProcessing Method of Register-SPWorkflowService.   8441be6c-6699-40a2-8dde-60e52a69238f    
11/07/2014 12:07:43.53  PowerShell.exe (0x244C) 0x2B08  SharePoint Foundation   Topology    aeayb   Medium  SecurityTokenServiceSendRequest: RemoteAddress: 'http://localhost:32843/SecurityTokenServiceApplication/securitytoken.svc' Channel: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.IWSTrustChannelContract' Action: 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/RST/Issue' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:3cec26d5-57f8-4813-b2d6-6eb0ae3f4b46' 8441be6c-6699-40a2-8dde-60e52a69238f    
11/07/2014 12:07:43.54  w3wp.exe (0x1628)   0x1A70  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nasq    Medium  Entering monitored scope (ExecuteSecurityTokenServiceOperationServer). Parent No    8441be6c-6699-40a2-8dde-60e52a69238f    
11/07/2014 12:07:43.54  w3wp.exe (0x1628)   0x1A70  SharePoint Foundation   Topology    aeax9   Medium  SecurityTokenServiceReceiveRequest: LocalAddress: 'http://spfeapp01.demo.net:32843/SecurityTokenServiceApplication/securitytoken.svc' Channel: 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel' Action: 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/RST/Issue' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:3cec26d5-57f8-4813-b2d6-6eb0ae3f4b46'    8441be6c-6699-40a2-8dde-60e52a69238f    
11/07/2014 12:07:43.55  w3wp.exe (0x1628)   0x1A70  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    Medium  Leaving Monitored Scope (ExecuteSecurityTokenServiceOperationServer). Execution Time=15.2904    8441be6c-6699-40a2-8dde-60e52a69238f    
11/07/2014 12:07:43.55  w3wp.exe (0x1628)   0x1A70  SharePoint Foundation   Claims Authentication   af3y9   Medium  STS Call Claims Windows: Successfully requested sign-in claim identity for user 'demo\sp_install'.  8441be6c-6699-40a2-8dde-60e52a69238f    
11/07/2014 12:07:43.58  PowerShell.exe (0x244C) 0x2B08  SharePoint Foundation   Topology    8xqz    Medium  Updating SPPersistedObject WorkflowServiceProxy. Version: 47080 Ensure: False, HashCode: 54367207, Id: b6f293c9-3542-4198-bc95-a2f7fca7423d, Stack:
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServiceApplicationProxy.Update() 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.PowerShell.RegisterSPWorkflowService.InternalProcessRecord() 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdlet.ProcessRecord() 
    at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord() 
    at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoExecute() 
    at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input, Hashtable errorResults, Boolean enumerate)                  
    at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame) 
    at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.LightLambda.RunVoid1[T0](T0 arg0) 
    at System.Management.Automation.DlrScriptCommandProcessor.RunClause(Action`1 clause, Object dollarUnderbar, Object inputToProcess) 
    at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoComplete() 
    at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.DoCompleteCore(CommandProcessorBase commandRequestingUpstreamCommandsToStop) 
    at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input, Hashtable errorResults, Boolean enumerate) 
    at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeHelper() 
    at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeThreadProc() 
    at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineThread.WorkerProc() 
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) 
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) 
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) 
    at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()  8441be6c-6699-40a2-8dde-60e52a69238f    
11/07/2014 12:07:43.61  PowerShell.exe (0x244C) 0x2B08  SharePoint Foundation   Topology    8xqz    Medium  Updating SPPersistedObject WorkflowServiceApplicationProxy Name=Workflow Service Application Proxy. Version: -1 Ensure: False, HashCode: 33145158, Id: f53478f8-a4b1-4a0a-a936-e84e8b780453, Stack:
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServiceApplicationProxy.Update() 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.PowerShell.RegisterSPWorkflowService.InternalProcessRecord() 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdlet.ProcessRecord() 
    at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord() 
    at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoExecute() 
    at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input, Hashtable errorResults, Boolean enumerate) 
    at System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.InvokePipeline(Object input, Boolean ignoreInput, CommandParameterInternal[][] pipeElements, CommandBaseAst[] pipeElementAsts, CommandRedirection[][] commandRedirections, FunctionContext funcContext) 
    at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`6.Run(InterpretedFrame frame) 
    at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame) 
    at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame) 
    at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame) 
    at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.LightLambda.RunVoid1[T0](T0 arg0) 
    at System.Management.Automation.DlrScriptCommandProcessor.RunClause(Action`1 clause, Object dollarUnderbar, Object inputToProcess) 
    at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoComplete() 
    at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.DoCompleteCore(CommandProcessorBase commandRequestingUpstreamCommandsToStop) 
    at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input, Hashtable errorResults, Boolean enumerate) 
    at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeHelper() 
    at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeThreadProc() 
    at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineThread.WorkerProc() 
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) 
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) 
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) 
    at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()  8441be6c-6699-40a2-8dde-60e52a69238f    
11/07/2014 12:07:43.63  PowerShell.exe (0x244C) 0x2B08  SharePoint Foundation   Topology    8xqz    Medium  Updating SPPersistedObject WorkflowServiceApplicationProxy Name=Workflow Service Application Proxy. Version: 53639 Ensure: False, HashCode: 33145158, Id: f53478f8-a4b1-4a0a-a936-e84e8b780453, Stack:
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServiceApplicationProxy.Update() 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.PowerShell.RegisterSPWorkflowService.InternalProcessRecord() 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdlet.ProcessRecord() 
    at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord() 
    at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoExecute() 
    at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input, Hashtable errorResults, Boolean enumerate) 
    at System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.InvokePipeline(Object input, Boolean ignoreInput, CommandParameterInternal[][] pipeElements, CommandBaseAst[] pipeElementAsts, CommandRedirection[][] commandRedirections, FunctionContext funcContext) 
    at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`6.Run(InterpretedFrame frame) 
    at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame) 
    at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame) 
    at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame) 
    at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.LightLambda.RunVoid1[T0](T0 arg0) 
    at System.Management.Automation.DlrScriptCommandProcessor.RunClause(Action`1 clause, Object dollarUnderbar, Object inputToProcess) 
    at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoComplete() 
    at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.DoCompleteCore(CommandProcessorBase commandRequestingUpstreamCommandsToStop) 
    at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input, Hashtable errorResults, Boolean enumerate) 
    at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeHelper() 
    at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeThreadProc() 
    at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineThread.WorkerProc() 
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) 
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) 
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) 
    at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()  8441be6c-6699-40a2-8dde-60e52a69238f    
11/07/2014 12:07:43.66  PowerShell.exe (0x244C) 0x2B08  SharePoint Foundation   Topology    8xqz    Medium  Updating SPPersistedObject SPServiceApplicationProxyGroup. Version: 47099 Ensure: False, HashCode: 21685505, Id: 804b6b49-344b-4de8-b9b3-ab0e50720934, Stack:
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPServiceApplicationProxyGroup.Update() 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.PowerShell.RegisterSPWorkflowService.InternalProcessRecord() 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdlet.ProcessRecord() 
    at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord() 
    at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoExecute() 
    at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input, Hashtable errorResults, Boolean enumerate) 
    at System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.InvokePipeline(Object input, Boolean ignoreInput, CommandParameterInternal[][] pipeElements, CommandBaseAst[] pipeElementAsts, CommandRedirection[][] commandRedirections, FunctionContext funcContext) 
    at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`6.Run(InterpretedFrame frame) 
    at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame) 
    at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame) 
    at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame) 
    at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.LightLambda.RunVoid1[T0](T0 arg0) 
    at System.Management.Automation.DlrScriptCommandProcessor.RunClause(Action`1 clause, Object dollarUnderbar, Object inputToProcess) 
    at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoComplete() 
    at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.DoCompleteCore(CommandProcessorBase commandRequestingUpstreamCommandsToStop) 
    at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input, Hashtable errorResults, Boolean enumerate) 
    at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeHelper() 
    at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeThreadProc() 
    at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineThread.WorkerProc() 
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) 
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) 
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) 
    at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()  8441be6c-6699-40a2-8dde-60e52a69238f    
11/07/2014 12:07:43.71  PowerShell.exe (0x244C) 0x2B08  SharePoint Server   State Service   8kg3    Medium  StateServiceApplication.OnDependentProcessIdentityChanged(): State Service Application - SPFEAPP01 (e490f244-e7a3-490f-8dcd-a9fbfd0cb68a) [1 databases] 8441be6c-6699-40a2-8dde-60e52a69238f    
11/07/2014 12:07:43.82  PowerShell.exe (0x244C) 0x2B08  SharePoint Foundation   Database    944r    High    Adding S-1-5-21-2559886674-2909965602-3489493778-1511 to the role, WSS_Content_Application_Pools, in the database, SrvDB_SPFEAP01_StateService. 8441be6c-6699-40a2-8dde-60e52a69238f    
11/07/2014 12:07:43.82  PowerShell.exe (0x244C) 0x2B08  SharePoint Server   State Service   b3s6    High    GrantAccessInternal(S-1-5-21-2559886674-2909965602-3489493778-1511): Granting to DB SrvDB_SPFEAP01_StateService 8441be6c-6699-40a2-8dde-60e52a69238f    
11/07/2014 12:07:43.91  PowerShell.exe (0x244C) 0x2B08  SharePoint Foundation   Database    944r    High    Adding S-1-5-21-2559886674-2909965602-3489493778-1510 to the role, WSS_Content_Application_Pools, in the database, SrvDB_SPFEAP01_StateService. 8441be6c-6699-40a2-8dde-60e52a69238f    
11/07/2014 12:07:43.91  PowerShell.exe (0x244C) 0x2B08  SharePoint Server   State Service   b3s6    High    GrantAccessInternal(S-1-5-21-2559886674-2909965602-3489493778-1510): Granting to DB SrvDB_SPFEAP01_StateService 8441be6c-6699-40a2-8dde-60e52a69238f    
11/07/2014 12:07:43.92  PowerShell.exe (0x244C) 0x2B08  SharePoint Foundation   Database    944r    High    Adding S-1-5-21-2559886674-2909965602-3489493778-1510 to the role, SPDataAccess, in the database, SrvDB_SPFEAP01_StateService.  8441be6c-6699-40a2-8dde-60e52a69238f    
11/07/2014 12:07:43.92  PowerShell.exe (0x244C) 0x2B08  SharePoint Server   State Service   b3s6    High    GrantAccessInternal(S-1-5-21-2559886674-2909965602-3489493778-1510): Granting to DB SrvDB_SPFEAP01_StateService 8441be6c-6699-40a2-8dde-60e52a69238f    
11/07/2014 12:07:43.93  PowerShell.exe (0x244C) 0x2B08  SharePoint Foundation   Database    944r    High    Adding S-1-5-21-2559886674-2909965602-3489493778-1510 to the role, db_securityadmin, in the database, SrvDB_SPFEAP01_StateService.  8441be6c-6699-40a2-8dde-60e52a69238f    
11/07/2014 12:07:43.93  PowerShell.exe (0x244C) 0x2B08  SharePoint Server   State Service   b3s6    High    GrantAccessInternal(S-1-5-21-2559886674-2909965602-3489493778-1510): Granting to DB SrvDB_SPFEAP01_StateService 8441be6c-6699-40a2-8dde-60e52a69238f    
11/07/2014 12:07:43.94  PowerShell.exe (0x244C) 0x2B08  SharePoint Foundation   Database    944r    High    Adding S-1-5-21-2559886674-2909965602-3489493778-1510 to the role, db_accessadmin, in the database, SrvDB_SPFEAP01_StateService.    8441be6c-6699-40a2-8dde-60e52a69238f    
11/07/2014 12:07:43.94  PowerShell.exe (0x244C) 0x2B08  SharePoint Server   State Service   b3s6    High    GrantAccessInternal(S-1-5-21-2559886674-2909965602-3489493778-1510): Granting to DB SrvDB_SPFEAP01_StateService 8441be6c-6699-40a2-8dde-60e52a69238f    
11/07/2014 12:07:44.02  PowerShell.exe (0x244C) 0x2B08  SharePoint Foundation   Database    944r    High    Adding S-1-5-21-2559886674-2909965602-3489493778-1510 to the role, db_owner, in the database, SrvDB_SPFEAP01_AppMgmt.   8441be6c-6699-40a2-8dde-60e52a69238f    
11/07/2014 12:07:44.02  PowerShell.exe (0x244C) 0x2B08  SharePoint Foundation   App Management  abihm   Medium  AppManagementSerivceApplication.OnDependentProcessIdentityChanged(): App Management Service Application - SPFEAPP01 8441be6c-6699-40a2-8dde-60e52a69238f    
11/07/2014 12:07:44.05  PowerShell.exe (0x244C) 0x2B08  SharePoint Foundation   Database    944r    High    Adding S-1-5-21-2559886674-2909965602-3489493778-1511 to the role, SPDataAccess, in the database, SrvDB_SPFEAP01_AppMgmt.   8441be6c-6699-40a2-8dde-60e52a69238f    
11/07/2014 12:07:44.06  PowerShell.exe (0x244C) 0x2B08  SharePoint Foundation   Database    944r    High    Adding S-1-5-21-2559886674-2909965602-3489493778-1510 to the role, SPDataAccess, in the database, SrvDB_SPFEAP01_AppMgmt.   8441be6c-6699-40a2-8dde-60e52a69238f    
11/07/2014 12:07:44.07  PowerShell.exe (0x244C) 0x2B08  SharePoint Foundation   Database    944r    High    Adding S-1-5-21-2559886674-2909965602-3489493778-1512 to the role, SPDataAccess, in the database, SrvDB_SPFEAP01_AppMgmt.   8441be6c-6699-40a2-8dde-60e52a69238f    
11/07/2014 12:07:44.12  PowerShell.exe (0x244C) 0x2B08  SharePoint Foundation   Database    944r    High    Adding S-1-5-21-2559886674-2909965602-3489493778-1510 to the role, SPDataAccess, in the database, SrvDB_SPFEAP01_Word.  8441be6c-6699-40a2-8dde-60e52a69238f    
11/07/2014 12:07:44.12  PowerShell.exe (0x244C) 0x2B08  Word Automation Services    Configuration   m2or    Medium  Database 'SrvDB_SPFEAP01_Word': Granting database access.   8441be6c-6699-40a2-8dde-60e52a69238f    
11/07/2014 12:07:44.12  PowerShell.exe (0x244C) 0x2B08  Word Automation Services    Configuration   m2t0    Medium  App 'Word Conversion Service Application Service - SPFEAPP01': Farm service account has changed, new identity = 'S-1-5-21-2559886674-2909965602-3489493778-1510', updating database to grant access 8441be6c-6699-40a2-8dde-60e52a69238f    
11/07/2014 12:07:44.16  PowerShell.exe (0x244C) 0x2B08  Word Automation Services    Configuration   m2os    Medium  Database 'SrvDB_SPFEAP01_Word': Database access granted.    8441be6c-6699-40a2-8dde-60e52a69238f    
11/07/2014 12:07:44.30  PowerShell.exe (0x244C) 0x2B08  SharePoint Foundation   Topology    8xqz    Medium  Updating SPPersistedObject WorkflowDeploymentProviderTypePersistedObject Name=WorkflowDeploymentProviderTypePersistedObject. Version: 47089 Ensure: False, HashCode: 24899870, Id: 4b5e9714-be33-4fca-8549-d633fe8d783e, Stack:
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServiceApplicationProxy.RegisterWorkflowLifecycleManagementEnvironment() 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.PowerShell.RegisterSPWorkflowService.InternalProcessRecord() 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdlet.ProcessRecord() 
    at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord() 
    at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoExecute() 
    at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input, Hashtable errorResults, Boolean enumerate) 
    at System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.InvokePipeline(Object input, Boolean ignoreInput, CommandParameterInternal[][] pipeElements, CommandBaseAst[] pipeElementAsts, CommandRedirection[][] commandRedirections, FunctionContext funcContext) 
    at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`6.Run(InterpretedFrame frame) 
    at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame) 
    at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame) 
    at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame) 
    at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.LightLambda.RunVoid1[T0](T0 arg0) 
    at System.Management.Automation.DlrScriptCommandProcessor.RunClause(Action`1 clause, Object dollarUnderbar, Object inputToProcess) 
    at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoComplete() 
    at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.DoCompleteCore(CommandProcessorBase commandRequestingUpstreamCommandsToStop) 
    at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input, Hashtable errorResults, Boolean enumerate) 
    at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeHelper() 
    at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeThreadProc() 
    at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineThread.WorkerProc() 
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) 
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) 
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) 
    at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()  8441be6c-6699-40a2-8dde-60e52a69238f    
11/07/2014 12:07:44.36  PowerShell.exe (0x244C) 0x2B08  SharePoint Foundation   Topology    8xqz    Medium  Updating SPPersistedObject WorkflowDeploymentGroupTypePersistedObject Name=WorkflowDeploymentGroupTypePersistedObject. Version: 47091 Ensure: False, HashCode: 51007600, Id: f0f5a80e-9feb-4aaf-9e86-abcf973d7881, Stack:
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServiceApplicationProxy.RegisterWorkflowLifecycleManagementEnvironment() 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.PowerShell.RegisterSPWorkflowService.InternalProcessRecord() 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdlet.ProcessRecord() 
    at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord() 
    at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoExecute() 
    at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input, Hashtable errorResults, Boolean enumerate)     at System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.InvokePipeline(Object input, Boolean ignoreInput, CommandParameterInternal[][] pipeElements, CommandBaseAst[] pipeElementAsts, CommandRedirection[][] commandRedirections, FunctionContext funcContext) 
    at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`6.Run(InterpretedFrame frame) 
    at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame) 
    at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame) 
    at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame) 
    at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.LightLambda.RunVoid1[T0](T0 arg0) 
    at System.Management.Automation.DlrScriptCommandProcessor.RunClause(Action`1 clause, Object dollarUnderbar, Object inputToProcess) 
    at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoComplete() 
    at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.DoCompleteCore(CommandProcessorBase commandRequestingUpstreamCommandsToStop) 
    at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input, Hashtable errorResults, Boolean enumerate) 
    at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeHelper() 
    at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeThreadProc() 
    at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineThread.WorkerProc() 
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) 
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) 
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) 
    at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()  8441be6c-6699-40a2-8dde-60e52a69238f    
11/07/2014 12:07:44.38  PowerShell.exe (0x244C) 0x2B08  SharePoint Foundation   Topology    8xqz    Medium  Updating SPPersistedObject WorkflowAppPartTypePersistedObject Name=WorkflowAppPartTypePersistedObject. Version: 47093 Ensure: False, HashCode: 2825417, Id: 4527f25c-501e-41e6-9ddf-67ff26bb9100, Stack:
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServiceApplicationProxy.RegisterWorkflowLifecycleManagementEnvironment() 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.PowerShell.RegisterSPWorkflowService.InternalProcessRecord() 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdlet.ProcessRecord() 
    at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord() 
    at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoExecute() 
    at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input, Hashtable errorResults, Boolean enumerate) 
    at System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.InvokePipeline(Object input, Boolean ignoreInput, CommandParameterInternal[][] pipeElements, CommandBaseAst[] pipeElementAsts, CommandRedirection[][] commandRedirections, FunctionContext funcContext) 
    at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`6.Run(InterpretedFrame frame) 
    at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame) 
    at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame) 
    at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame) 
    at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.LightLambda.RunVoid1[T0](T0 arg0) 
    at System.Management.Automation.DlrScriptCommandProcessor.RunClause(Action`1 clause, Object dollarUnderbar, Object inputToProcess) 
    at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoComplete() 
    at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.DoCompleteCore(CommandProcessorBase commandRequestingUpstreamCommandsToStop) 
    at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input, Hashtable errorResults, Boolean enumerate) 
    at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeHelper() 
    at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeThreadProc() 
    at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineThread.WorkerProc() 
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) 
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) 
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) 
    at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()  8441be6c-6699-40a2-8dde-60e52a69238f    
11/07/2014 12:07:44.41  PowerShell.exe (0x244C) 0x2B08  SharePoint Server   Workflow Services   ahq9q   Medium  Unexpected retrieval of property on WorkflowServiceApplicationProxy:    8441be6c-6699-40a2-8dde-60e52a69238f    
11/07/2014 12:07:46.42  PowerShell.exe (0x244C) 0x2B08  SharePoint Foundation   PowerShell  91ux    High    Error Category: InvalidData    Target Object  Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.PowerShell.RegisterSPWorkflowService  Details  NULL  RecommendedAction NULL 8441be6c-6699-40a2-8dde-60e52a69238f    
11/07/2014 12:07:46.42  PowerShell.exe (0x244C) 0x2B08  SharePoint Foundation   PowerShell  6tf2    High    Microsoft.Workflow.Client.WorkflowEndpointNotFoundException: Unable to connect to the remote service at http://localhost:12991/SharePoint/. See InnerException for more details. Client ActivityId : 8441be6c-6699-40a2-8dde-60e52a69238f. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:12991 
    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult) 
    at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
```

Comment: Can you make sure there is a site binding for Workflow Management Site on port 12291? also check this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/d3147100-4d1e-4237-b543-42d6168aa65b/no-connection-between-sp2013-and-workflow-manger?forum=sharepointgeneral

Answer (score 2):

If your server is running on Windows Server 2012 **R2** make sure you install Workflow Manager **CU2** which requires Service Bus **CU1** as a prerequisite.

Comment: Have installed Workflow Manager Refresh 1.0 directly, I hope it includes everything.

Comment: FWIW, I had the same problem several months ago and installing the CU2 worked for me. Link: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2902007